# How to setup SSH on a Raspberry Pi A+ Without using a USB Hub

Tags: ssh, remote, setup, pi-a+

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi A+, and I want to control it remotely with SSH, but I cannot set it up because it has only 1 USB port, which means I can plug in a mouse or a keyboard or a WiFi adapter (In my case it is my phone using USB Tethering) one at a time. In order to setup SSH, I have to enter commands in the terminal using the keyboard, but those commands require an internet connection, so I plug my phone, but now how I can type?! I do not have a USB hub and I am not willing to buy one, so is there any way I can setup SSH with only 1 USB port?

Comment: In case it isn't clear, the point of the duplicate is that all you have to do to enable ssh is to add a file called `ssh` to the first partition on the card -- which you can do from any computer.  You do not have to "enter commands in the terminal using the keyboard".

Comment: @goldilocks Every tutorial I found includes commands. If it is only a matter of putting a file on the card then that's great! Is it just an empty file? If not then where I can download it from?

Comment: It's an empty file.  Beware when you read stuff online (including here) that Raspbian (and pi software generally) has gone through changes over the years, so look for a date (we have dates).  If there is no date but they refer to "wheezy" as the OS version, it is probably at least a few years old.